# UIWebview on scroll event

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I want to know how to call a method in the event that a user has stopped scrolling on a page inside UIWebview.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Please expand the question with more detail and code examples

Comment: Basically what i have is a UIWebview controller on my app. The user will use this uiwebview to look at a page. but when the user scolls on the page, a separate function is called external to the uiwebview. you might know how a UITextField can respond to events such as "editing did begin" or "touch up inside". i want something similar for the uiwebview where for example: "scrolling did end".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`UIScrollView` has also a subView of the `UIWebView` :

So you can fire at the *delegate of UIScrollView's* :

```
webView.scrollView.delegate = self
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
   //Do your  Stuff
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView 
                  willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{
    if (!decelerate) {
        //Do your  Stuff
    }
}
```

Check the [Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html)

Comment: Is it safe to reassign the delegate of a grandchild object like this?

Comment: Consider using KVO on the `contentOffset` property of the child `scrollView` instead. It doesn't have to be safe to modify the delegate property of the `UIScrollView` since `UIWebView` can be using it internally.