# Swift 3 - Detect non-activity in UIWebView

Tags: swift, xcode, uiwebview

I want to be able to detect if there is no user activity (e.g. scrolling / tapping) in UIWebView. I have only found a code which detects tapping, but not scrolling in UIWebView.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: view, action: #selector(handleSingleTap))
    tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
}

@objc func handleSingleTap(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    //Do something here with the gesture
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set the webview's scrollview delegate to self.

```
webView.scrollView.delegate = self
```

and conform to the delegate methods `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating`, `scrollViewDidEndDragging`, `scrollViewDidScroll`, `scrollViewWillBeginDragging`

Within these methods, check for changes in content offset and using that you can calculate if scrolling took place or not.

> Find the details in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23029893/2570153) and [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollviewdelegate).